# Unit Testing with Mock. Parent does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm trying to write a unit test and coming across the error,

> Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined.

I've had a look to see what this means and I see it mentioned that there is no public constructor.  Only thing is, my code does have this so I'm confused why there is this error.

This is the unit test..

```
public void CalculateVat_ReturnsCorrectAmount()
{
    // Arrange
    const decimal expectedResult = 2;

    _mockSingleValueParameter = new Mock<ISingleValueParameterService>();
    _mockItemCache = new Mock<ItemCache>();
    _mockReferenceDataService = new Mock<ReferenceDataService>();

    _Calculator = new CostCalculator(_mockSingleValueParameter.Object, _mockItemCache.Object,
        _mockReferenceDataService.Object);
    // end

    //.....    
}
```

The line

```
_calculator = new CostCalculator(_mockSingleValueParameter.Object, _mockItemCache.Object,
            _mockReferenceDataService.Object)
```

is the one that throws the error.

This is the constructor of `CostCalculator`..

```
public CostCalculator(
    ISingleValueParameterService singleValueParameterService, ItemCache cache, ReferenceDataService referenceDataService);
{
    _itemCache = cache;
    _singleValueParamService = singleValueParameterService;
    _refDataService = referenceDataService;
}
```

There is other code in the project that looks just like this as well but works..I can't understand what the difference is between them.

TIA!

Comment: So `ItemCache` and `ReferenceDataService` look mighty like concrete classes. Are they abstract? Why are you mocking them, if not?

Comment: They aren't abstract, they are both "public class".  I should probably say my unit testing knowledge is very limited.  I thought mocking the objects mimicked the behaviour of the object so when testing should use a mock version of the object.  I'm guessing I'm wrong?

Comment: What are `ItemCache` and `ReferenceDataService`? Can they be refactored to abstractions?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include `ItemCache` and `ReferenceDataService` so that a proper assessment can be made of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mock a concrete class instead of an interface, it must have a default constructor (i.e. no parameters) and any methods you want to perform setups on must be virtual.

In your case it looks like either `ItemCache` or `ReferenceDataService` (or both) are lacking default constructors.

Comment: You can't mock a concrete class using `MOQ` BTW?

Comment: @Rahul yes you can mock a concrete class using moq. It is not usually advised, but it works. Caveats not withstanding.

Comment: @Rahul `Mock` also allows you to pass arguments to the constructor of mocked concrete classes if required.

Comment: Ah ok, so am I understanding this right then...._calculator is an interface but the error is because I'm mocking the parameters to create this (_mockSingleValueParameter, _itemCache & _refDataService).  And this is because these do not have default constructors?

Comment: @dataCruncher02 correct. Do they need to be mocks or can you just use the real implementation? If they need to be mocks, and you can't change your design to use interfaces and mock those, then you need to add default parameters or pass arguments to the mock constructors.

Comment: @dataCruncher02 now this is why it is usually advised to not have your classes depend on implementation concerns (concrete classes), but rather on abstractions (interfaces or abstract classes).

Comment: @OwenPauling how do you know if they need to be mocks?  Sorry I know this is probably unit testing 101